# Debug doesn't show code crash point

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2003

I used to debug an application some time ago and when it crashed it would interrupt on the crash file code part location, Lately when debugging it, it crashes, but when it interrupting it only show the disassembler, is it some configuration? I'm using visual studio 2003 (also it says the fault address is 0x00000000)

Comment: try to use valgrind if VS fails.

Comment: Valgrind doesn't run on Windows.

Comment: my bad, i'm used to Unix/Linux and i was sure about Valgrind distributed for Windows, you can always use MinGW and try to debug it with gdb or use Valgrind alternatives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

Comment: Sometimes VS program database files (pdb) got confused/corrupted for some reason. It is especially for big projects. Try to do full rebuild.

Comment: Also, I suspect you know that VS can't debug a file with more that 65535 lines of code http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/7d991493-06f7-45f6-8f34-165b988e266c/

Comment: Do the debugger show the callstack properly?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, no it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible reasons:

**A.** The debugger didn't find the PDB for the module which is crashed, because:

1) It is a release build.

2) The crash is in a system DLL.

**B.** The memory is corrupted so badly that the debugger is unable to analyze the call stack.